# How do I write a story about forbidden love?

Tags: characters, writers-block

I have two characters, a boy named Kai and a girl named Raya. They also are stuck in a love triangle with another boy named Alejandro but Kai and Raya aren't allowed to be lovers.  Raya and Alejandro are still allowed to be in love but Raya doesn't know which one she loves. Alejandro liked her because she was kind and strong but Kai liked her since they were kids.

Comment: Who gets who in the end?

Comment: To some extent, how you tell the story will depend on why they are not allowed. If it's because their respective families are having a fight, for example, it's one thing. That gets you Romeo and Juliette. If it's because they are brother and sister, that's quite another. Now it's Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 1):

**Develop your characters**: Kai and Raya should have distinct personalities, backgrounds, and motivations that make them relatable and interesting to readers. It's important to explore their thoughts and feelings about each other, as well as the reasons why they are forbidden to be together. This will help readers empathize with them and become invested in their story.

**Create tension and conflict**: You'll obviously explore what exactly prevents the couple from being together. Is it social norms, family expectations, or personal beliefs? Think about what is keeping Kai and Raya apart and how this conflict can escalate throughout the story. This will keep readers engaged and eager to see what happens next.

**Show, don't tell**: Instead of simply telling readers that Kai and Raya are in love, show them through their actions and dialogue. This can include subtle gestures, meaningful glances, and intimate conversations that reveal their true feelings for each other.

**Explore themes**: Forbidden love stories often touch on themes such as loyalty, sacrifice, and the power of love. Consider what themes you want to explore in your story and how they can be integrated into the plot and character development.

**Avoid stereotypes**: Love triangles can be a common trope in fiction, but it's important to avoid falling into stereotypes and cliches. The forbidden love is a common one, so this is something to look out for. And try to give each character depth and complexity, rather than simply portraying them as objects of desire.

Remember, writing a good story is a process of exploration and discovery. Don't be afraid to try different approaches and experiment with your characters and plot. Good luck with your writing!